# easy CRUD plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, web-applications

I am looking for a plugin or other component that will allow easy CRUD operations on a single table in my database.  We have a list of providers that needs to be maintained (edits of address and phone) and delete and add providers via a web page.  Does anyone have a recommendation for something in Eclipse or java that will allow me to point at my table and allow modifications?

Thanks!

Leslie

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (not tested directly) you could have a look to **[EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)**.

(More specifically, [EclipseLink DBWS](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/dbws.php) for [Web services](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/DBWS))

[image]